# Error. Failed to load pdf document in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to load pdf file in html but i got an error.

here is my function

```
 public function getDocument($file){
      $filePath = 'app/final/attachments/AA-19-4-2019-18123/'.$file;
      $type = Storage::mimeType($filePath);
      $pdfContent = Storage::get($filePath);

      return Response::make($pdfContent, 200, [
         'Content-Type'        => $type,
         'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.$file.'"'
      ]);
 }
```

here is my route

```
 Route::get('/documents/pdf-document/{file}', 'inboxController@getDocument');
```

and here is my code in blade

```
 <embed src="{{ action('inboxController@getDocument', ['file'=> basename($attach)]) }}" style="width:100%;height:auto;overflow: hidden;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

it seems like, the error is because of the filename of the file. When i changed it to asdf.pdf, it loaded the file, but when i change its filename i wont loaded anymore. Images doesnt have really a problem. only pdf files. Please help me

edit

when i tried to use this static code, then remove {file} from route and also in blade, then pdf will loaded. i cant figure it out why.

```
 public function getDocument(){
      $filePath = 'app/final/attachments/AA-19-4-2019-18123/my.pdf';
      $type = Storage::mimeType($filePath);
      $pdfContent = Storage::get($filePath);

      return Response::make($pdfContent, 200, [
         'Content-Type'        => $type,
         'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.$file.'"'
      ]);
 }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  What is the filename that doesn't work?

Comment: now, when i tried to delete the history, all filenames doesnt work anymore. i dont know it wont loaded. But when i tried to remove the {file} in my route. and do a fixed filename in my function and changed my embed to <embed src="{{ action('inboxController@getDocument') }}" style="width:100%;height:auto;overflow: hidden;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen> then, pdf file loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way :

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Next Go to the storage folder under 'public', and create a Folder 'FOLDER_NAME'

Your function :

```
 public function getDocument($filename){

    return response()->file('storage/FOLDER_NAME/'.$filename);
}
```

In your routes, web.php :

```
Route::get('/pdf/{filename}', ['as' => 'filename', 'uses' => 'ControllerName@getDocument' ]);
```

Then you can call it from your blade :

```
<a href="/pdf/{{ 'name_of_your_file' }}" target="_blank">See PDF File:</a>
```

Comment: thank you. but i want it to store in embed without clicking a link

Comment: You can just call the route with the file name and it will display the pdf. It's not necessary to call it from a clicking link. I just showed it , if you want to call this pdf file from another route.

Comment: i tried your way, and i tried my way. but both forcingly downloading the file. it didnt show up in my embed